# Ошибка:" not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python-3.x

Дано число `a`, например `923 451`. Надо получить:

```
923451
92345
9234
923
92
9
0
```

Мой код:

```
q=(923451)
while int(q)>0:
    str(q)-str(q)%10
    print(q)
```

Ошибка:

> not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: `str(q)%10` -- непонятно зачем вы пыталась остаток от деления у строки получить. Кроме того, `%` для строк это оператор форматирования строк, например `print("abc = '%s'" % 123)`

Comment: 0. зачем сохранять число во множество? 1. зачем конвертировать в строку? 2. зачем делить строку на 10 и брать остаток?

Comment: @Эникейщик, `(923451)` - является целым числом, а не кортежем, как это может показаться ;)

Comment: @MaxU Да, точно :)

Comment: Я понял свою ошибку, благодарю что помогли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = int(input())

while a > 0:
    print(a)
    a = a // 10
print(0)
```

Comment: Это задание https://stepik.org/lesson/213098/step/5?unit=186305

Comment: Спасибо, все компилируется